# Can not load properties file from the web-inf folder in Websphere 8.5 server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, properties-file

I am trying to load a properties file from WEb-INF folder in my web application , which is running on Websphere 8.5 . I am using below code  to load the file from the location

```
public class Init {
private  final String WEB_INF_DIR_NAME="WEB-INF";
private  String web_inf_path;
private  final Properties APP_PROPERTIES =null;
InputStream inputStream = null;
public  String getWebInfPath() throws IOException {
    if (web_inf_path == null) {
        web_inf_path = URLDecoder.decode(Init.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF8");
        web_inf_path=web_inf_path.substring(0,web_inf_path.lastIndexOf(WEB_INF_DIR_NAME)+WEB_INF_DIR_NAME.length()).substring(1);
    }
    inputStream = Init.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/localhost/accountservice.properties");
   // inputStream  = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config/localhost/accountservice.properties");
    if (inputStream != null) {
        APP_PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);
     }
 System.out.println(APP_PROPERTIES.getProperty(AccountServiceDataAccessConstants.INET_LIBRARY_NAME)); //  Here i am getting NULL
    return web_inf_path;
}
   }
```

I have also tried using servlet context , but its also giving me NULL. I have tried all possible ways to solve it but unfortunately i am not able to do it. I am also giving my folder structure.

[image]

Please excuse me if this is a silly  question , but i am not really getting any idea about it.

Comment: As far as I know, property files are located in the resources folder. You can define your resources folder in your pom.xml if you're using Maven. Usually, they are located in `/src/main/resources`. From there, you can access to it the way you did: `MyClass.class.getResourcesAsStream(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually, everything in WebContent is placed in the root of your WAR file. So instead of

```
inputStream = Init.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/localhost/accountservice.properties");
```

It would be

```
inputStream = Init.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/localhost/accountservice.properties");
```

The root of the WAR has WEB-INF in it, and then you can descend into your folder structure as normal.

Comment: To expand on that... the WEB-INF directory itself is not generally part of the web module's class path.  By default, you'll get the WAR root, the WEB-INF/classes directory, and jar files in WEB-INF/lib (but not the WEB-INF/lib directory itself).  If you don't want to have WEB-INF in the getResource argument, you could move your "config" directory structure either up to the parent or down into WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Extract and check your generated WAR file. Is the file where you expect it to be?